# jQuery prevent selecting nested divs

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, nested

I have the following HTML structure:

```
<div class="comment">
   ...
   <div class="comment">
   </div>
   ...
</div>
```

I need to select the parent  element with class "comment" but only the main one, not the nested ones.

The problem is, i cant use something like this:

```
$("parent > .comment")
```

because the main  is given in variable.

Comment: Do you want to add a listener to it or what ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `filter` method:

```
$('div.comment').filter(function(){
    return !$(this).parents('.comment').length;
});
```

Or:

```
$('div.comment').filter(function() {
    return !$(this.parentNode).closest('.comment').length;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HYNAb/

Comment: No, I withdraw my previous comment: [`parentsUntil()` was a *silly* idea](http://jsperf.com/test-of-parents-againsts-parentsuntil).

Comment: @DavidThomas You are right, `parents` is _overkill_, I updated the answer using `closest` method.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/BDxA5/3/
would here be possible to prevent triggering mouseenter event on "nested comment" ?

Comment: `closest()` is, on Chromium 25/Ubuntu 12.10, not faster (albeit not significantly slower, either): [JS Perf](http://jsperf.com/test-of-parents-againsts-parentsuntil).

Comment: @DavidThomas Yes, I just tested it and weirdly `parents` was faster than `closest`.

Comment: @domagoj412 You can use `stopPropgation` method of the event object, but using this method for `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events results in unexpected behaviours, I have updated your fiddle(_not using `stopPropagation()`_), although I don't recommend it, http://jsfiddle.net/FeVsq/

Comment: @undefined How do you measure the speeds of these commands? (just curious)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.comment').filter(function(){
  if($(this).closest('.comment').length > 0)
  return false;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
$("div.comment").not("div.comment > div.comment")
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the structure you presented, with just one nesting level, this works:

```
$(".comment:has(.comment)")
```

It selects only elements with class `comment` that have child elements with class `comment`

Alternatively, if you want to select elements with class `comment` that have nested divs, you can do this:

```
$(".comment:has(div)")
```

Answer (score 0):

Provided that the nested ones are direct children, you should be able to use:

```
$('.comment .comment').parent();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try use [parents](http://api.jquery.com/parents/) :

```
$('.comment').parents('.comment');
```